# Defining functions and if statement problems

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with two functions and an if statement. I'm being told the functions `go` and `postcodeChange` are not defined.

I'm also being told `flag` is an unexpected identifier at `if flag == 1`.

Any idea where I am going wrong? Thank you.

```
function postcodeChange(){
document.getElementById("goButton").onclick = distanceCheck;
}

function distanceCheck(){
var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value
var patt1=new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1})?$");
var out = patt1.exec(distance);

if (out == null) {
    //distance is not a valid number
    document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value = 1
} 
else {
    //distance is valid number
    document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value = 0
}

function go(){
var flag = document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value
if flag == 1
{
    alert("Distance is not valid- enter a number with no more than one decimal point");
}
else{
    popSubmit('#fa Care Provider Search Go','','0');
}
}
```

Comment: `if flag == 1` should be `if (flag == 1)`.. using full indentation will save you a lot of hassle, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions not being defined are a direct consequence of the syntax error - with the syntax error, the functions can't be understood and are therefore not defined.

So, regarding that syntax error, I'm pretty sure the parentheses around an `if` conditonal are mandatory:

```
if( flag == 1)
```

EDIT: Also, as Wouter points out, you missed a `}` to end your `distanceCheck` function defintion. And another thing, please terminate your lines with `;` or prepare for nasty surprises. <del>JavaScript will screw you over otherwise!</del>

Comment: Naah. not in this case. Only if something like this would be written: `var a = "hello World", b = a` and then on the next line `(function() {/*...*/})()` This will be evaluated  as `b = a(function(){})()`

Comment: True, but getting into the habit will save heartache later.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the distancecheck function.

```
function postcodeChange(){
document.getElementById("goButton").onclick = distanceCheck;
}

function distanceCheck(){
var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value
var patt1=new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1})?$");
var out = patt1.exec(distance);

if (out == null) {
    //distance is not a valid number
    document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value = 1
} 
else {
    //distance is valid number
    document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value = 0
}
}

function go(){
var flag = document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value
if flag == 1
{
    alert("Distance is not valid- enter a number with no more than one decimal point");
}
else{
    popSubmit('#fa Care Provider Search Go','','0');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The If Statement is not correct :

Use

```
if(flag==1){//your statement}
else {//your statement}
```

and the function scope of `distanceCheck()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
function postcodeChange(){
    document.getElementById("goButton").onclick = distanceCheck;
}

function distanceCheck() {
    var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value
    var patt1=new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1})?$");
    var out = patt1.exec(distance);

    if (out == null) {
        //distance is not a valid number
        document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value = 1
    } 
    else {
        //distance is valid number
        document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value = 0
    }

// }
// should we close the function here ? 
// Or is `go` a function inside the function `distanceCheck`:

    function go(){
        var flag = document.getElementById("distanceFlag").value
        if ( flag == 1 ) { // <-- Use parantes' when dealing with if-statements 
            alert("Distance is not valid- enter a number with no more than one decimal point");
        }
        else {
        popSubmit('#fa Care Provider Search Go','','0');
        }
    }
// Nether the less you will need to close the function scope somewhere if not above then down here:
}
```